# wp_dropdown_pages default value

Tags: pages, dropdown, select

I have a dropdown menu of pages, but after I go to a page selected, let's say "About us", the default title button of dropbown is the title of the page, "About us", so i want the title/default option to be "Please select a page" or something like that.

My code is this:

```
wp_dropdown_pages("title_li=&depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&selected=$currPage");
```

What i'm doing wrong or how my code should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, that you switch from "URl query argument" style to arrays. This is a "feature" that is more a left over on some functions that is only available for backwards compatibility reasons than anything else.

Here's a reworked version of your current arguments:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( array(
    'title_li'    => '',
    'depth'       => TRUE,               // originally: 1,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'child_of'    => $post->post_parent,
    'echo'        => FALSE,              // originally: 0,
    'selected'    => $currPage,
) );
```

Now I wonder how you managed to display that dropdown/select element when `echo` was set to `0`/`false` and no `echo`/`print` was prepended to that statement. If you are just adding it to your template like this, you better set `echo` to `TRUE`.

From looking at the `selected` argument (and as you can read in the docs in Codex), this is the argument that chooses what element currently is `selected`. As you are setting it to `$currPage`, which I assume that it contains the current page slug, it shows you exactly that. To "fix" your problem, simply set it to an empty string `''`.

About the first/non-selected value: You can set that with the `show_option_none` argument

```
'show_option_none' => 'Please select a page',
```